# Get value from my own web control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write one example to create own control on ASP.NET Froms. The controls very simple- combobox and button. User need choose value and when after he submit the button, the value from combobox need display in label.
So. Code of my Control:

```
public class MyControl:Control,IPostBackEventHandler
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute("size","1");
        writer.AddAttribute("ID","List2");
        writer.AddAttribute("name", "ListYear");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Select);

        for (int i = 1950; i < DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Option);
            writer.WriteEncodedText(i.ToString());
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }

        writer.RenderEndTag();

        writer.AddAttribute("type","submit");
        writer.AddAttribute("value","ClickMe");
        writer.AddAttribute("name","BtnChange");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
        writer.RenderEndTag();

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    public delegate void OnClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);

    public event OnClickEventHandler Click;

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        Click(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

The Page ASP:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestMyControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hello.TestMyControl" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Hello" namespace="Hello" tagPrefix="MyContrl" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
    <MyContrl:MyControl runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed1_OnClick" ID="Control1"></MyContrl:MyControl>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the end Event function:

```
protected void Unnamed1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text="You choose "+Control1.????+" year";
    }
```

What substitute for a question mark that take the value from the list?

P.S. Something strange is going on. Because when I click the button, the handler is not called, and I can not get into Unnamed1_OnClick

Comment: It appears that your custom control has no way to get the text from it. Add a method or field then call it.

Comment: Either reference your control or cast `sender` as the type of your control and access the property you want to display in the `Label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set the value on an attribute, to retrieve it you need to access `Attributes` property

Make your control inherit from `HtmlControl`

```
public class MyControl : HtmlControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    ...
```

On your page

```
<MyContrl:MyControl runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed1_OnClick" ID="Control1"></MyContrl:MyControl>
```

On your code

```
Label1.Text = Control1.Attributes["value"];
```

You can debug this line to see all available attributes

Comment: Do you mean like this? Label1.Visible = true;
            Control1.Attributes["value"]; But this code throw error: 'Hello.MyControl' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method

Comment: @JonMaximys instead of inheriting from `Control` change to `HtmlControl`, then it should work.

Comment: Label1.Text = HtmlControl.Attributes["value"] as string;
Throw Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl.Attributes.get'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the name of the `combobox` and its the value of the text that is selected.

Like this:

```
protected void Unnamed1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text="You choose "+ myCustomControl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() 
    + " year";
}
```

(Sorry.  I misread the initial post and edited my code accordingly once I realized my mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

Add select list to your user control with name="YourSelectList"

then in the click event handler

```
protected void Unnamed1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text="You choose "+Control1.YourSelectList.SelectedValue.ToString()+" year";
    }
```

Comment: I added name, But when I write Control1. -> I see only public method like OnClickEventHandler and RaisePostBackEvent